# Can separate manifold regions have the same coordinates?

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces

Despite referring to physics, this question is purely mathematical on geometry and topology of the given pseudo-Riemannian manifold.

**Case A**

As a starting point, consider the Schwarzschild solution extended to the interior of the horizon. Here we have two regions, external and internal with known different properties.

We can describe the global spacetime (disregarding the maximal Kruskal extension) by two regions of the Schwarzschild coordinate chart, internal and external. (In this question, I am not concerned with the horizon boundary.)

**Case B**

Now consider a thin, hollow, massive shell of dust collapsing under a spherical symmetry to its Schwarzschild radius. As known, the spacetime outside the shell is Schwarzschild while the spacetime inside is time dilated Minkowski.

We can describe this spacetime by two regions of a chart in the Schwarzschild coordinates. So far, so good.

**Problem**

A trouble begins in the frame of the collapsing shell where the proper time to the Schwarzschild radius is finite. There we have two logical options:

1. The proper time of the shell ends at the horizon. In this case, the above mentioned coordinate chart (Case B) covers the entire global spacetime manifold (short of the horizon boundary perhaps).
2. The shell in its frame continues through the horizon. Then, per the Penrose Singularity Theorem, a singularity must form on the inside. In this case the spacetime there should look somewhat similar to the Schwarzschild extension (Case A).

In this case we end up with two spacetime regions on the inside: one is time dilated Minkowski (before crossing the Schwarzschild radius in the shell proper time) and the other is similar to extended Schwarzschild with a singularity (after the crossing). They seem to overlap over the same set of the Schwarzschild coordinates: for any $t,r,\phi,\theta$ there exist two different events in these spacetimes.

**Question**

> Can two different regions of the same global spacetime manifold share the same coordinates?

Sorry for the lack of rigor, I am not a mathematician. If any clarification or additional conditions are required, I would be happy to provide. Please do not hesitate to ask. Thanks for your expert insight!

---

**EDIT** - Based on comments, below is a clarification on the terminology used in the question. Nothing new here, just some optional background for clarity.

**Schwarzschild**

The Schwarzschild spacetime is a pseudo-Riemanian manifold defined by the following metric in polar coordinates:

$$ -{d \tau}^{2} = -\left(1 - \frac{r_\mathrm{s}}{r} \right) \,dt^2 + \left(1-\frac{r_\mathrm{s}}{r}\right)^{-1} \,dr^2 + r^2 d\Theta^2 $$

Where $d\Theta^2$ denotes the spherical metric induced by the Euclidean on a two sphere, i.e.

$$ d\Theta^2 = d\theta^2 + \sin^2\theta \, d\varphi^2\;\;\; \text{and} \;\;\; r=\sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2} $$

Here $r=r_s$ is a sphere of the *event horizon*, a coordinate singularity where the temporal part of the metric is zero while the spatial part radially diverges. The Schwarzschild metric accurately describes the gravitational field outside an uncharged non-rotating spherical object, such as a planet, star, black hole (or a hollow spherical shell in this question).

By extending this metric through the horizon, we notice that $t$ becomes spacelike while $r$ becomes timelike on the inside. This extension is the mainstream interpretation of the spacetime geometry inside an uncharged non-rotating black hole.

It is easy to see that a timeslice inside the horizon in the Schwarzschild coordinates is a spherinder rapidly shrnking in time $r$ to its axis (along $t$) called the Schwarzschild singularity, an infinite line $(r=0,-\infty<t<+\infty)$ removed from the spacetime manifold: [Is the Schwarzschild singularity stretched in space as a straight line?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2929400/is-the-schwarzschild-singularity-stretched-in-space-as-a-straight-line)

In this question, in the Case A, the Schwarzschild metric applies both outside and inside the horizon; in the Case B, this metric applies only outside of the massive spherical shell.

**Minkowski**

The Minkowski spacetime in a hollow massive shell is a flat pseudo-Euclidean manifold defined by the following metric (where $t\equiv x_0$):

$$ -{d \tau}^{2} = -H\, dx_0^2 + dx_1^2 + dx_2 + dx_3^2 $$

or in polar coordinates:

$$ -{d\tau}^2=-H\,dt^2+dr^2+r^2d\Theta^2 $$

See Weinberg, "Gravitation and Cosmology", p. 337 where $H$ is denoted as $f(t)$.

Here $H$ defines the time dilation (squared) and can be renormalized to unity in the coordinates inside the shell, but not in the Schwarzschild coordinates, because $dt$ must be continuous through the shell (the same time dilation inside as at the shell):

$$ H=1-\dfrac{r_s}{R} $$

where $R$ represents the radius of the massive shell, so the time dilation is the same anywhere inside the shell, at any radial coordinate $r$. See: [On a Common Misunderstanding of the Birkhoff Theorem](https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/pdf/10.1142/S2010194512006642) where $H$ is denoted as $h(t)$.

In this question, this metric applies to the Case B inside the massive spherical shell while the shell is larger than the horizon $r>r_s$ (which is forever in the Schwarzschild coordinates).

Comment: Coordinate charts typically overlap, and on the overlaps we have transition functions, which are diffeomorphisms.

Comment: By definition, a coordinate chart $\phi: U\subset M\rightarrow V\subset \mathbb{R}^4$ is a homeomorphism. So two points in $U$ cannot map to the same point in $V$. There is a lot of terminology in your question that I am unfamiliar with. It would be helpful if you could explain the situation in purely mathematical terms.

Comment: I think you will be better off posting this question in Physics Stack Exchange since they will probably better understand your perspective.

Comment: I don't understand everything you wrote, but I have a feeling you may be looking at a covering space of a base space.

Comment: @Malkoun Can you please point me to any info on the subject you mentioned? Thank you!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space

Comment: Roughly speaking, locally around each point on the base space, you can find an open set whose preimage under the covering map, is a disjoint union of copies of that open set. So if you are looking at two such open sets in the covering space, they may "look" like they are coordinates of "the same region", but if you do things carefully, you will distinguish between a covering space and a base space. I am not sure if this is what you are looking at, but it is just an intuition.

Comment: Try to give an explanation of "coordinate chart". Usually it is that what Vishnu M said in his first comment, and this means that different regions *by definition* cannot have the same chart. But perhaps you mean something else?

Comment: @PaulFrost We have two observers probing the structure of spacetime. The external observer sees the spacetime inside a collapsing shell as flat forever, nothing strange. The shell reaches the horizon in an infinite time. Yet the shell observer  reaches the horizon in a finite proper time and continues on (passed the infinite time of the external observer) to cross the horizon where the topology and geometry of spacetime is very different in the same coordinate system. Thus we have two regions of spacetime overlapping the same coordinates. Is this mathematically possible?

Comment: @PaulFrost See the last diagram here to visualize the spacetime structure: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/426143/intuitively-why-do-attempts-to-delay-hitting-a-black-hole-singularity-cause-you/427025#427025 - The fall from C to D takes forever outside, but then continues from E to F through the curved and flipped spacetime inside. Yet the external observer always sees the spacetime inside over the same coordinate points as flat and not flipped. So each coordinate point points to two different events in two different regions of the manifold. Possible or not? Please help! Thank you!

Comment: @Malkoun Thanks for the reference, but I don't see how it would apply here. A covering map in essence is a homeomorphism, a relation between two spaces. However, in this question I have two regions of the manifold that have nothing in common, just occupy the same coordinates in the coordinate system. I.e. each coordinate point points to two events, one in the first region and the other in the second region. However, these two events are unrelated with no logical or causal connection between them. One may be me blinking my eyes while the other may just be a point in empty spacetime.

Comment: @Malkoun As an illustration, consider two parallel $\Bbb R^2$ planes in $\Bbb R^3$. There is a map of Europe on one plane and my portrait on the other. Both occupy the same X and Y range, but have different Z coordinates. This makes sense. Now consider that there is no Z dimension in this manifold. So what remains looks like two overlapping surfaces occupying the same X and Y coordinates. There is no requirement for this manifold or the surfaces to be flat. And, while this illustration is 2D, the regions in the question are 4D. I doubt this is possible, but I need an expert opinion.

Comment: Consider the region in the plane defined by $x^2 + y^2 <= 1$. It is a disk with boundary. Now consider a sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$. Assuming you don't see the $z$-coordinate, you will notice that there are two points having the same $(x,y)$ coordinates if $x^2+y^2<1$, one above and one below. But the actual manifold is in this case a sphere. Maybe (and again I am not sure in your case, because I don't understand the details), you are looking at something similar to this.

Comment: @Malkoun Thanks, it starts making sense, but let me confirm. My actual manifold is not empty, it contains a map of Europe and my photograph in two separate regions at the same coordinates or, in your terminology, in a 2-to-1 cover. Now you and I go there to see what we find. In my question, there are two ways to get there.  You take one, I take the other. We get to the same coordinate location. You see the map of Europe, I see my photograph. We never meet in the eternity of time. Is this how the cover works? Or would we meet and see my photo superimposed on the map of Europe?

Comment: We never meet, as we actually are in different regions of spacetime, that only appear to be the same region after projecting.

Comment: @Malkoun This essentially answers my question pending a couple caveats. (1) Ignoring angles, the coordinates inside the spherical shell are $r,t$. The caveat is that in one region, $t$ is timelike and $r$ is spacelike, but in the other region this is reversed, $t$ is spacelike and $r$ is timelike. Does the covering map allow this? (2) The manifold is pseudo-Riemannian, locally Minkowski, twice differentuable and so on - real spacetime. Does any of this prevents the discussed cover? With this, can you please just copy/paste your comments as an answer? There is a bounty on this question 50+25 :)

Comment: @safesphere, I am sorry for deleting my answer. I feel my answer is not precise, and does not answer completely what you are asking. In particular, it does not answer the original problem which motivated you. As PaulFrost suggested, it is better to have an extended discussion with a Geometer, rather than via a forum.

Comment: @Malkoun It is fine Sir, no need to have an answer you don’t feel good about :) Although I thought it did address my original question. Can you post an answer you’d be happy with? Also, I’d love to have a discussion with a Geometer, but I am not at a university. This forum is the only way I can reach mathematicians. You are a Geometer. Your posts on PSE are way more sophisticated than my elementary problem here with the Schwarzschild and Minkowski metrics. Can we talk? Perhaps chat or email? It’s fine if you don’t want to. Thanks for your help anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not easy at all to try to guess what would happen without setting up the problem mathematically and trying to solve it.

If you are interested in the problem of a massive shell of dust collapsing, and the resulting spacetime geometry, well you have to set up the problem, namely write down the stress-energy tensor for this problem and try to solve Einstein's equations.

This is probably too difficult to attack by brute force, so to speak. I would try to look first at what has been done in the literature on that problem and possibly similar problems.

Especially in an area like GR, it is not at all clear how to guess what the solution metric looks like, even qualitatively (at least not for me!).

I think this is the main problem you are interested in. I did not provide an answer (as it is a research project on its own), but I did provide some guidelines that would hopefully be useful to you.

Regarding the mathematical language, local coordinates are just numbers to describe the local position of a point. You can have different sets of local coordinates to describe the same local region on a manifold. It is a bit like using two different maps to describe locations on the surface of the earth. In flat space, you could for instance use coordinates coming from an orthonomal coordinate system, but you could also for instance use spherical coordinates. The same metric would look very different in $2$ different coordinate systems, but if you inspect things closely, you would notice that the intrinsic properties are the same. It is like having two different descriptions of the same space. This leads to the notion of two metrics being isometric.

Edit 1: It seems that what safesphere is really interested in, is the notion of a covering space. The OP's questions can be subdivided into two categories: topological and Riemannian.

Let us start with the topological side. Without getting too much into technicalities, let us just say that covering spaces are closely related to the notion of fundamental group. There are known sufficient conditions for the existence of covering spaces, but let us just say that these conditions are satisfied if the base space (the space you are trying to build a covering space of) is a connected topological manifold. If the base manifold is further simply connected, there aren't any "interesting" covering spaces, while if the base manifold is not simply connected, there are some "interesting" covering spaces. I am being vague and sweeping a lot under the rug. For details, you can look at Munkres's Topology for instance, or Hatcher's book on topology (which was free to download at some point).

An example of an interesting covering space, is $SU(2)$, which is diffeomorphic to the $3$-sphere, and is a $2$ to $1$ covering space of $SO(3)$, itself diffemorphic to the $3$-sphere with antipodal points identified (thus diffeomorphic to real projective $3$-space).

There are more general types of covering spaces, called branched covering spaces, which occur naturally in algebraic geometry. This makes answering your topological questions more complicated.

Working out the topology of the covering space is usually not difficult in specific problems, where the topology of the base space is known. Let us just say that the topology of a covering space is closely related to that of the base space. It is in some sense the topology of the base space, but unwrapped a number of times (the number of times possibly being infinite).

Here is an example of an interesting covering space. The real line $\mathbb{R}$ is a covering space of the circle $S^1$, thought of as the unit circle in the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$. Indeed, the map $p : \mathbb{R} \to S^1$ defined by $p(t) = e^{2 \pi i t}$ is a covering map. In this case $p(t+n) = p(t)$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

As to the Riemannian part of your question, a covering map in the Riemannian sense, from one Riemannian manifold to another, is first of all a covering map in the topological sense, such that the pullback of the metric on the base manifold is the metric on the covering manifold.

So for covering maps in the Riemannian sense, "above" a (small enough) local neighborhood of a point on the base manifold, lie a disconnected union of isometric copies of that neighborhood. In other words, the copies in the covering manifold are isometric (look the same as) to the local neighborhood in the base manifold.

You may then ask: can't we, say, glue two copies of two different manifolds. You can, but then you lose the notion of a covering. It will be a topological gluing construction. You take two manifolds and glue them together, basically. I don't think this is what the OP really wants to do. Moreover, if you want to glue two Riemannian manifolds, you will have to make sure that the metric is smooth even where you do the gluing. This is in general very difficult (and is often impossible) to satisfy.

Now can we have a metric on a covering space (in the topological sense) which is not related to the metric on the base manifold? You could of course, but in practice, the natural metric on a covering space is the pullback metric (which thus looks locally like the metric on the base manifold).

It is difficult to answer your $4$ questions more precisely, as the answer will depend on how you translate them into precise mathematical statements. What I mean is: are you asking about covering spaces, or perhaps more general branched covering spaces?

I will just say that for covering spaces, usually the topology and (natural) metrics on the covering manifold are very closely related to those of the base manifold. However, for branched covering spaces, the situation is more complicated due to the existence of a branched locus.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! May I please ask to clarify some points? (1) In your example, the sphere is embedded in $\Bbb R^3$ and so is easy to visualize. Now, consider this is not two hemispheres of a sphere, but two separate intrinsically curved spaces and there is no embedding dimension (like $z$). Also, both spaces are 4D  (both in the same range of coordinates) and curved such that imagining them isometrically embedded would each require an affine space of 6D or more. If I understand correctly, none of this affects your answer. Can you please confirm if such spaces can still be a 2-to-1 cover?

Comment: (2) Is there any topological restriction on these spaces? Can two spaces of different topology represent a 2-to-1 cover? The spaces in the question are $\Bbb R^2\times\Bbb S^2$ (homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^4\setminus\text{line}$ - the fact that this coordinate line is not covered by this space, but only by the other space is fine for my purposes) and $\Bbb R^4$. And finally two points (1) and (2) in my last comment under the question (just to confirm none of this matters). Thanks again!

Comment: “*If you are interested in the problem of a massive shell of dust collapsing, and the resulting spacetime geometry*” - No, I am simply asking if there is a concept in mathematics for two separate regions of the manifold to overlap the same coordinates in a chosen coordinate system without actually overlapping (e.g. without the observers in these regions ever meeting). The collapsing shell is just an illustration of the concept, not the question per se. While the concept of the covering space ended up edited out, it did answer the question, so I am awarding the bounty. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Now with that clarification and the formalities out of the way, can you please help with 4 remaining yes/no points numbered in the comments above? **Assuming** that the Schwarzschild and Minkowski spacetimes both cover the same coordinate base inside the horizon. Whether or not this situation results from the gravitational equations is out of scope. The question is, **if** it does, then what? E.g. is there any logical contradiction? And what is the topology of this cover? Thanks again!

Comment: Just to clarify one more time to avoid any confusion, two coordinate systems in the same manifold region that you and Paul mention are exactly the opposite of my question that is about two different manifold regions sharing the same coordinates in a single coordinate system.

Comment: I did my best to answer your questions in the Edit 1 section of my answer. Thank you for the points.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a real answer, but an extended comment. In my opinion there is a big problem: We have the language of physics and the language of  mathematics, but we do no have a good interpreter. I am sure that good interpreters exist, but I do not belong to them. Perhaps you should talk to mathematicians at your univerisity, an intensive dialog is much better than a conversation in a forum.

That being said, I think the situation is this:

You have two observers watching the same spacetime region. In the language of manifolds, this region is an open subset $U$ of the spacetime manifold $M$. Depending on their position they see different things, formally they use *different local coordinate systems* for $U$. A local coordinate system is a homeomorphism $\phi : U \to V$, where $V$ is an open subset of the standard Euclidean space $\mathbb R^4$. There are infinitely many such local coordinate systems for $U$. As a simple example in dimension $1$ take the set $S = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid x^2 + y^2 =1, x, y > 0 \}$ . This is an open quarter circle and the maps $f : (0,\pi/2) \to S, f(t) = (\cos t, \sin t)$, and $g: (0,1) \to S, g(t) = (t, \sqrt{1-t^2})$, are homeomorphisms. Their inverses are local coordinate systems for $S$. The first of them describes what an observer sees from the origin $(0,0)$, the second what an observer sees from a distant point $(0,R)$ with $R >> 1$. Now consider a point moving couterclockwise with constant speed along $S$ in direction $(0,1)$. The first observer sees this point moving with constant speed, but the second observer sees that the speed goes to $0$ as the point approaches $(0,1)$.

Comment: Thanks so much for trying to help! I appreciate it :) However, my case seems to be reversed. You state, "*You have two observers watching the same spacetime region** - in different coordinates. Instead they observe two different regions of spacetime, which both appear at the same coordinates in the same coordinate system. The observers take different paths to get there and once their coordinates (in the same coordinate system) are the same, they don't meet, but observe completely different content around. I didn't expect this to be logical, but since have learned the concept of covering space.

Comment: The external observer sees the shell slowing down at the horizon and never crossing it. The spacetime inside is always empty and flat. The observer on the shell is assumed to see himself crossing the horizon in a finite proper time and see the shell crushing to end in a singularity. His timeline inside is $r$, as radius becomes timelike, and it occurs after the eternity of the external time $t$ in the global (Schwarzschild) coordinate system. If we put the first observer inside the shell and use local coordinates for both, they still see different things inside, not the same thing transformed.

Comment: @safesphere So perhaps it is the other way: You have two charts $\phi_i : U_i \to V$ to the same $V \subset R^n$.Then both observers  look at the same $V$ which corresponds to two different regions $U_i$. This is similar as viewing two different films on the same screen. But as I said: Try to discuss this with other people at your university, it will be much more efficient to get a common understanding.